# Displaying representation symbology description in legend of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, legend, representation

When a layer with Representations is turned on, how do you change the 'Description' in the Legend. The setting is normally under the symbology tab and it is not visible when Represenations are turned on. The layer is shown in the legend as the field it is shown on.

Can you modify the 'description' under symbology to show the title of the layer as any text you type in?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Slight modification in loki's Answer; in Layer Properties, Symbology tab settings, under Representations, chose the Representation you wanna modify, and edit the lable as you want. If want to change the Polygon as line, add line instead of polygon representation, or by deleting any unwanted representation...

figures for you reference..[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Arc Map 10.1 it's working this way:

Right click on the shape-layer, choose "Properties", click on "Symbology", choose "Categories", then choose your Symbology.

Now you can edit the Labels for each class in the column "Label". These will appear in the Legend.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  However, I do not think that your Answer will apply to this Question because you do not seem to have taken account of the asker using [**Representations**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000004m000000).

Comment: Yes, when using Represenatations, the feature is a polygon being displayed as a line, there is a rule applied through the representations tab. The normal categories and label in that area would not apply.

Comment: PolyGeo, do you know if you can make the legend display the representation polygon as a line, and change the label in description?

Comment: @CarlaGB That sounds like it should be asked as a new question, but I am not sure that it is one that I will try to answer because I am rusty on Representations.