# How can I change layer names in my legend when using layers with representations? Arcgis 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, legend, representation

When using a Feature Class layer with symbology converted to a representation there is no option in the symbology tab of the layer's properties to enter legend text. I can't see any options in legend properties. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89753/displaying-representation-symbology-description-in-legend-of-arcgis-for-desktop) ?